# Cannot run python-escpos methods

Tags: python, thermal-printer, escpos

I have an Epson thermal printer (TM-82), connected via USB. I am using [python-escpos](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos) library (version v2.2.0) I am trying to run some of [Escpos module's](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos/blob/development/src/escpos/escpos.py) methods such has `ln()`, `textln()`, etc. But none of these commands work, and I get an error `'Usb' object has no attribute <method_name>`. The only commands that work are `text()`, `qrcode()`, `barcode()`, `image()` and `cut()`.

Can you guys please tell me what's wrong?

**Steps to reproduce**

```
>>> from escpos import printer
>>> p = printer.Usb(0x04b8, 0x0e11, 0)
>>> p.text('hello')
>>> p.ln()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Usb' object has no attribute 'ln'
>>> p.is_online()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Usb' object has no attribute 'is_online'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using python-escpos 2.2.0, look at the [source and documentation for that version](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos/blob/v2.2.0/src/escpos/escpos.py).

There is no `ln` or `is_online` function in that version.

Comment: Yes, my bad! Thank you!